# ginput to uitable

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, matlab-uitable

This seems like a relatively simple problem. I want to have the data from my ginput function print to a uitable (or text box, whatever is easier) in my GUI. I cannot seem to figure this one out. The ginput is activated with a push button, so I am guessing I need to set the data into the uitable somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem using

```
set(handles.uitable, 'Data', ginputData)
```

Rookie error...